# reference undefined at multiple files

Tags: cross-referencing, multiple-files

I am having touble to getting my labels and references working. I have a multifile-setup where I have the `\label` in one file and the `\ref` in the other.

Whatever I do, I always get

```
./evaluation.tex:420: LaTeX Warning: 
Reference `EqSoftmax' on page 34 undefined on input line 420.
```

Does someone know a soliution for this problem?

---

***main.tex***

```
...
\include{systemdescription}
\include{evaluation}
...
```

***systemdescription.tex***

```
...
\begin{align}
\sigma(z_j) = \frac{e^{z_j}}{\sum_{k=1}^{|Z|} e^{z_k}} \;. \label{EqSoftmax}
\end{align}
...
```

***evaluation.tex***

```
...
and applied the softmax function (Equation \ref{EqSoftmax}) 
...
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Did you compile more than once?

Comment: Off-topic for your question, but if you use the `cleveref` package, it can automatically insert "Equation" if you reference an equation.

Comment: if you do not have `\includeonly` then the cross references will resolve on the second run of latex

Comment: The tag [tag:labels] is **not** meant for the referencing system!

Comment: I'm actually using overleaf.com for my work. So it should have been compiled a lot more often than one time... the \includeonly seems also not to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Off-topic for your question, but if you use the cleveref package, it can automatically insert "Equation" if you reference an equation.

Actually, using cleverref solved the problem. 
Just make sure, that \usepackage{cleverref} is included last.
Thanks @samcarter